# Fit text in container without breaking word using HTML/CSS only

Tags: html, css, word-break

On my webpage I've used fancybox for preview section of description text in popup. Text shows perfectly fine on desktop but on popup it shows something like this.

> Please note that the descriptive text I'm getting for the display it include `&nbsp;` for each space user gives for the sentence after each word.

[image]

and when I use `word-break: break-all;` it gets like this

[image]

then I've used `word-break:break-word;` also and get this

[image]
[image]

you can spot the difference now, that it breaks word viz clearly not acceptable. I want to break sentences meaningfully not the word!

Problem is I can only use HTML/CSS only here for fixing this, have looked many que/ans here but no luck.

Please help me into this.

I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/5u7L50bw/1/) please look into this may be this will help to understand clearly.

Comment: did you try "word-wrap: break-word;", or try googling as many other times this has been asked. You say you tried looking around, but share nothing about what else failed, or if you tried any other word-break values.

Comment: `@Daniel Brose` as you can See I've used that property but it not what I want.
I don't want to break word unnecessarily. I just want to fit the text inside container.

Comment: Can i have ur code jsFiddle, So i can easily find out

Comment: No, you didnt - 'break-word' is not 'break-all'. This example shows that only 1 character is broken (googling becomes googlin-g on 'break-word'. https://jsfiddle.net/1acbtr82/

Comment: And this one, using "word-break:keep-all" breaks NO characters: https://jsfiddle.net/dabros/1acbtr82/1/

Comment: Please be calm.
As I said I've used  
word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE 5.5-7 */
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox 1.0-2.0 */
white-space: pre-wrap;  

but the thing is I've get the same result as in image-2 it breaks word viz I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** If you don't want to modified server side scripts, you can use this JavaScript solution instead. I don't think you can do so with CSS only without doing any amendments in your server side code to remove these `&nbps;`.

In that case, you should first decode HTML special chars to simple text using following JavaScript code.

```
var text = $("<textarea/>").html('your HTML encoded text here with &nbsp; and all').text();
$('your viewing div/p selector').html(text);
```

And add this CSS property in your viewing `div` or `p`.

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

It should work.

Comment: `@shashwat` thanks a lot for your effort!.

Although you've solved this with `jQuery` but nevermind it worked for me.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay Coz such things like replace something with something else is something which you can't do with pure CSS. Added a note on the top.

Answer (score 0):

Use [word-wrap:break-word;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/word-wrap)

It even works in IE.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible values of the css "word-break" property.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp

```
word-break:break-word;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1acbtr82

```
word-break:keep-all;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dabros/1acbtr82/1/

The first works fine but does break up "googling" into "googlin-g", the second refuses to even do that.